# ¿Como puedo hacer que el valor de una variable cambie por el valor de un select?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Quiero hacer que una variable de una hoja "ReporteController.php" (la variable la dejo estática para que se muestre bien el ejemplo de la imagen mas abajo, pero lo que quiero es que sea una variable $ListAnio).

```
   $ANIO = '2021' /* puede ser también sin comillas */;
```

Acá brindo el codigo completo:

```
public function report( Request $request, Response $response, Sargs) {
SANIO = '2021' /* puede ser tambien sin comillas */;
SrepoSerie = new RepoSeries($this->container) ;
= new RepoBCR($this->container);
$repoBer
new RepoSBS($this->container);
$repoSbs

$repoOsei = new RepoOSEI($this->container) ;
$repoVenta = new RepoVenta($this->container);
$repoTasa = new RepoTasas ($this->container);
= $repoSerie->ListarDistritos(4) ;
$distritos
= $repoSerie->ListarSeriesTipo(4);
$codigos

$repoBer->ejecutarConsultar( 'GET' , $codigos, '2021-1' , '2025-1' ) ;
Sdata
= $repoBer->ejecutarConsultar( 'GET' , 'PD37944PQ' , '2021-1' , '2025-1' );
$PrecioM2Data
$TipoCambio
$DataOsei

$reposbs->consultarTipoCambio() ;
$repoOsei->ListarData($ANIO) ;
= $repoVenta->minutasActuales (SANIO);
SdataOptima
= $repoTasa->creditoHipotecario(SANIO) ;
SdataCreditoHipo

* var_dump ($data); die(); */
Svariables = [
"distritos" => $distritos,
"ventas" => $data[ 'periods' ][0]['values' ],
"precioM2" => $PrecioM2Data[ 'periods' ][0][' values' ],

"tcVenta" => $TipoCambio[4],
"tcCompra" => $TipoCambio[2],
"dataOsei" => $DataOsei,
"dataOptima" => $dataOptima,
"dataCreditoHipo" => $dataCreditoHipo

echo _DIR_;die();
$content = $this->container->get( 'view')->fetch( 'rot. twig', $variables);
Srenderer = new PhpRenderer(_DIR_. '/ . ./template/ ' , $variables);
return $renderer->render($response, "reporte.php", $args) ;
```

y en mi select que esta en la hoja "reporte.php"

```
   <form action="ReporteController.php" method="post">
        <div id="selector" style="padding-bottom: 2rem;">
            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                <!-- <option selected>-- Seleccionar Año --</option> -->
                <?php 
                $ListAnio = ['2021', '2022', '2023', '2024'];
                var_dump($ListAnio);
                foreach($ListAnio as $ListAnio){
                    echo '<option value="'.$ListAnio.'">'. $ListAnio .'</option>';
                ?>
                <?php }?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Ahora, como hago para que cuando seleccione un dato del select, el valor de la variable $ANIO cambie/actualice, sin usar ajax.

[image: En la imagen se ve que obtiene bien el array, pero cuando selecciono otra fecha, no actualiza la los datos, solo se queda con el año asignado estaticamente.]

Comment: Buenas, debes mostrar el código de como llenas los listados y la relación que tienen los listados con el año que quieres que se seleccione..

Comment: Puedes usar Fetch

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: No recuerdo mucho sobre PHP pero parece que esta función es el handler del POST que realizas cuando cambia el select, correcto? Si ese es el caso lo más probable es que la información que buscas esté dentro del body que se envía en el objeto `$request`, recuerda agregarle un `name` al select para que se envíe dentro del body del form

Comment: deberias de colocar el codigo en textro vita colocar codigo en imagenes, eso no sirve para ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hay que tener en cuenta dos datos inportantes:***

1. PHP se ejecuta del lado del servidor; eso quiere decir que para poder cambiar algo del php tienes que enviar esa informacion del lado del usuario hasta el servidor.
2. El codigo HTML es estatico siempre; se vuelve dinamico al implementar javascript que es codigo que se ejecuta en el navegador y te permite hacer cosas con el DOM  y HTML para luego enviar datos al servidor u obtenerlos.

***Entonces existen dos formas de cambiar una variable en php:***

1. Enviando por ajax dicho dato y evitar que refresque toda la pantalla; refrescando o actualizando los datos solo del contenido al obtener la respuesta del servidor.
2. hacer un submit Html que envie los datos al servidor y los procese esto provocara que la pagina se refresque y procese la nueva informacion.

**Respuesta:** no hay manera de hacer lo que pides; no se puede evitar el uso de un metodo ajax, fetch, XMLHttpRequest o un submit para enviar los datos al servidor y cambiar el dato que contiene tu variable `$ANIO`

Entonces si decides enviar los datos por alguno de estos metodos es muy probable que tu variable llegue al lado del servidor, pero debes ponerle un atributo `name` para que puedas identificarla dentro del array GET o POST y puedas usarla de esta forma:

***Html:***

```html
<select name="prueba">
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
</select>
```

***PHP:***

```php
$ANIO = $_POST["prueba"];
```

***Como enviar datos al Servidor?***

***Con ajax `jQuery`:***

```js
var menuId = $( "ul.nav" ).first().attr( "id" );
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { id : menuId },
  dataType: "html"
});
 
request.done(function( msg ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( msg );
});
 
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

***Con `fetch`:***

```js
// Ejemplo implementando el metodo POST:
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Opciones por defecto estan marcadas con un *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

postData('https://example.com/answer', { answer: 42 })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `data.json()` call
  });
```

***Con `XMLHttpRequest`:***

```js
// Set up our HTTP request
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Setup our listener to process request state changes
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

    // Only run if the request is complete
    if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;

    // Process our return data
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
        // This will run when the request is successful
        // It checks to make sure the status code is in the 200 range
        console.log('success!', xhr);
    } else {
        // This will run when it's not
        console.log('The request failed!');
    }

    // This will run either way
    // All three of these are optional, depending on what you're trying to do
    console.log('This always runs...');

};

// Create and send a GET request
// The first argument is the request type (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.)
// The second argument is the endpoint URL
xhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, realizare las pruebas y estare comentando. gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude solucionarlo, gracias de nuevo por la ayuda y el apoyo.